# Is Compulsion or other weaves cancelled by a Stedding?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

A stedding cuts a wielder of the One Power off from the source, stopping their power.

But what if a weave has been set? Would that also be ended iby a stedding? For instance, would a Compulsion, which is cast on the mind, cease to work or even vanish if the victim was taken to a stedding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we know about [Stedding](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Stedding#Characteristics) are that they cut a channeler of from the True Source (and also a Darkfriend off from the True Power of the Dark One).  As per the extract below from the Wiki:

> An Ogier Stedding is a beautiful place. An aura of peace and well-being can be felt by anyone inside one, channelers and non-channelers alike. They are populated by what the Ogier refer to as Great Trees, of which little is known.

> The other main characteristic of the Stedding is that it blocks access to the True Source for Channelers.  This blocking effect also extends to the True Power of the Dark One.  **Robert Jordan has answered some questions on what happens to existing One Power effects when one enters a Stedding. The Warder Bond and a shield that has been tied off on a channeller (eg Asmodean) remain intact, but a Mirror of Mists disguise would unravel upon entry.**  Brandon Sanderson has likewise given some answers that imply that the Stedding have much the same effects on channelers as Far Madding's Guardian ter'angreal, meaning that it would be possible to use a Well inside a Stedding. He also stated that an a'dam would still function and that a circle would not be broken, but that none of the linked parties would be able to channel.

As stated, an existing tied off weave (such as [Compulsion](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Compulsion?so=search)) would not be affected by the entry into a Stedding, it would only affect an ongoing maintained weave like [Mirror of Mists](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_of_Mists).

Interestingly, the question was asked about a year ago on [Dragonmount](https://dragonmount.com/forums/topic/114381-would-a-stedding-undo-existing-weaves/), a Wheel of Time fan forum.